# How can i calculate my private formula on php?

Tags: php, html, forms

How can i calculate my formula?,, i've tried many codes but it's still doesn't work for me...
Here is the code...

```
include generator.html;

function calculate_string( $mathString )    {
    $mathString = trim($mathString);
    $mathString = ereg_replace ('[^0-9\+-\*\/\(\) ]', '', $mathString);
    $compute = create_function("", "return (" . $mathString . ");" );
    return 0 + $compute();
}


$a = $_GET['nformatif'];
$b = $_GET['nuts'];
$c = $_GET['nuas'];
$submit = $_GET['submit'];

$string = " ( $a * 2 / 10 ) + ( $b * 3 / 10 ) + ( $c * 5 / 10 )"; 
echo calculate_string($string);
```

and this is the generator.html

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<input  type="text" name="nformulatif" maxlength="10" size="10">
<input  type="text" name="nuts" maxlength="10" size="10">
<input  type="text" name="nuas" maxlength="10" size="10">
<input  type="submit"  name="submit"></form>
```

can anybody help me?...
sorry,, i'm newbie... X(

Comment: What is this formula you speak of? Does it have an algorithm? Also your `form method` is `post` so you should use `$_POST['nformatif']`

Comment: Tip: don't use `ereg_replace`, is deprecated. Use `preg_replace` instead.

Comment: It's still doesn't work,, i use `$_POST['']` and replace `erg_replace` with `preg_replace`...

Comment: Can you edit your question with the changes you made to your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your formula is static you should make a function with it.

```
function your_formula_name($a,$b,$c){
    return ( $a * 2 / 10 ) + ( $b * 3 / 10 ) + ( $c * 5 / 10 );
}

$a = $_GET['nformatif'];
$b = $_GET['nuts'];
$c = $_GET['nuas'];

echo your_formula_name($a,$b,$c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sloved!

```
include 'generator.html';

function calculation($a,$b,$c){
    return ( $a * 2 / 10 ) + ( $b * 3 / 10 ) + ( $c * 5 / 10 );
}

$a = $_GET['nformulatif'];
$b = $_GET['nuts'];
$c = $_GET['nuas'];



if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {

    echo calculation($a,$b,$c);

}
```

Thanks for helping me...